UPS circuit: voltage drops when raspberry pi zero boots
I am powering a raspberry pi zero through the following module: https://techobsessed.net/tag/mh-cd42/ as there is a lithium battery powering everything, in case of lack of power from USB.
The problem I have is that when the raspberry boots, the voltage suddenly drops for a brief moment to 4.4v, that is not enough to power the raspberry pi zero, and the boot is interrupted and restarts.
I guess the reason is that the raspberry at a certain point during boot draws more current and the module cannot handle it. This surprises me as the module is rated for 2.1A and the Raspberry pi zero does not draw more than 1A, while the battery is already charged at 100% so it should not be drawing much current.
Question 1: is there a way to "support" the circuit for that brief moment when the voltage drops, so that the raspberry can complete boot?
Question 2: is there a similar module that has better specifications?

Q2 probably yes

what is brief moment?

Do you have any recommendation for an alternative module? I can't really measure a brief moment as the raspberry reboots, therefore the voltage returns to normal levels. It takes 1 second or less.

Are you sure it's not the opposite? Some powerbank chipsets turn themselves off when the intended application is to charge phones and they drop their current draw to low levels so the powerbank turns off.

No because the LEDs of the module stay on. If the raspberry wasn't drawing enough current the LEDs of the module would turn off.

no recommendations... shopping questions are not allowed here
